# How to list all shared items?

Tags: google-keep

Is there a way, a search string maybe, for Google Keep to list all my shared items (either shared by me or shared with me)?

Comment: This may be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922964/how-do-i-view-the-storage-of-a-chrome-extension-ive-installed/27434046

Comment: This is either a question for [webapps.se] or [android.se], unless there is a Google Keep app for Windows.

Comment: @Mokubai I see, thanks - what's the best way for me to migrate it to Web Applications?